# Where to store settings in Django application?

Tags: django, settings

I want to be able to change some of the settings defined in settings.py file in run time. The changes should also be kept (after server restart). I found https://github.com/jabapyth/django-appsettings but it lacks support for arrays and tuples. Is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings are not meant to be changed at runtime.

Doing this could lead to threading issues and inconsistencies, as they are loaded at the start by each worker upon initialization, so you change them in one process and the others don't have the updated value.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

**Edit**

If you manage to store those settings into the data model, you can take advantage of the low-level cache system, so almost no query happens until data is changed and you invalidate those values manually. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api .

**Edit 2**

You can add a very simple and generic setting model, and manage it through the admin interface or whatever.

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    value_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('s','string'),('i','integer'),('b','boolean'))

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    def actual_value(self):
        types = {
            's': str, 
            'i':int, 
            'b': (lambda v: v.lower().startswith('t') or v.startswith('1'))
        }
        return types[self.value_type](self.value)
```

For site-wide settings, attach to a Site model, for User-specific setting, attach to a User etc.

**Edit 3**

You can use Manager objects to return lists or dicts:

```
class SettingManager(models.Manager):
    def dict_for_object(self, object):
        ct = ContentType.get_for_model(object)
        pk = object.pk
        return dict(self.filter(object_id=pk, content_type__id=ct.id).values_list('name', 'value'))
```

Comment: I dont mind the inconsistency, because all i want to change are quotas, accepted files extensions, etc.

Comment: That is exactly the point. Say your WSGI server has 5 workers, you may want to change your QUOTAS setting with a request. The worker that happened to receive the request may honor your change, but the other four workers have no idea of the change.

The best way would be to have the actual settings changed, and to restart the entire app.

Comment: Or, if those settings are not to be changed by someone able to restart the app, then they don't really belong to the `settings.py` file. Think about putting them into your data model.

Comment: is there a way to define static fields in python/django?

Comment: You don't need static fields, a one row table (one instance model) will do what you need.

Comment: but it's not aesthetic and practical (one instance - one setting)

Comment: what do you mean by static fields? you could put your variables (the ones that need to be changed) into a specific file and import it wherever you need. But i don't like it that much... if you have a "user" class in your model, you could just add those variables to the class, and so you can modify them directly in the DB. So you can have different values for each user (eg, the quota)

Comment: Please post an example of a setting that you'd want to change.

Comment: OK, this looks fine. I'll extend your generic model by adding method returning queryset (filter by name will fake the list, tuple) and add caching. I can't see how to fake a dict, but it's gonna be good enough. Thanks.

Comment: To retrun querysets or dicts, in general multiple objects, you declare the method in a Manager. See edit.

Comment: You can't query over pickled fields' content. For the rest, it may work.